# Creating random image outlines on python

Tags: python, algorithm, image, random

As to kill time i thought of doing this,

creating random pixels with diffrent colour on screen using python

[image: Randomly generated colours]

then i basically want to connect the dots, so i though of doing prims on the coloured pixel, thus i would grow a tree, in turn an outline of a random image

Does anyone know any good algorithm libary for python that supports this?
i can write this manually (an approximation of prims, not exact), but if there is a solution exists, i don't want to waste time.

Also do anyone think its just a waste of time doing this?

Comment: You're killing time, but you don't want to waste time?  Sounds like you have a bit of a dilemma on your hands.

Comment: true, but i want to do something that is usefull,
initially i was thinking of producing an image using sound (in matlab)

Comment: how could you waste something that has already been killed?